# OData metadata and URIs

Tags: odata, uri, metadata

First off, I'll say that this is no where near my field of expertise. I am pulling this data into an Excel Power Query from a public OData feed, below is the metadata url:

https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/MasterWebService/PublicApi/frads/v1/odata/gcis/$metadata

When I request a dataset, it returns a "Crossing" with each of those Properties defined in that metadata above (can't post a link to a dataset since it requires a token), but below is essentially what's returned.

```
<ArrayOfCrossing>
<Crossing>
<Property></Property>
</Crossing>
</ArrayOfCrossing>
```

Where I am lost, is how I drill down into that metadata and return the metadata about each property. For instance, the property 'CntyCD' (County) returns a code that refers to a County. Instead of the code, I want the County name.

What I have tried:

- Reviewing OData 2, 3, and 4 URI references
- Spent hours reviewing different sites, reading and trying all sorts of different URI combinations

There's not much documentation on the API website other than forming basic queries.

If anyone could take a look at this metadata url and help me understand the "shape" of the metadata or point me to any resources I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this later, the answer is you cannot derive any additional metadata from this. You have to build your own lookup tables from various sources on their website.

My source to this solution is the folks who administer the data source (Federal Railroad Administration) who pointed me to this URL: https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/OfficeofSafety/publicsite/DownloadCrossingInventoryData.aspx

The above url contains various lookup tables in CSV format under the heading “Reference Data and Documents”, as well as a pdf explaining the coding for each field. From what I can see, most of the fields have their values listed in one or more of those downloadable files.

Not the solution I was hoping for, but it works. I was hoping to get the values from a query and not by maintaining my own table data, which will need to be updated as they make any changes to their lookups.

Comment: while what you say is true, this is not an answer that is likely to benefit the wider community.

Comment: You have also indicated that you are not an expert in this subject matter, so just wait for a response from someone who is. ;)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I updated my answer to include more details regarding the solution. Yes, I am not the expert, but I asked the folks who administer the data source and that was the answer provided. They would be the experts on their own data. I hope this clarifies things. I asked them to consider delivering the lookup values with the payload, they said they would “pass it on”.

Comment: Wonderful, the main issue with your initial response is that other readers and search aggregators will interpret it as "OData does not provide a way to lookup metadata" when in fact it's just that this is a very poor example of what OData _can_ do.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I agree. I wish their data source was more robust. Hopefully they take my suggestion to add additional metadata and this will be irrelevant in the future.

Answer (score 1):

OData is great, `$metadata` is a rich descriptive language that allows the API developers to express the structural bounds of the schema. A well defined service $metadata you should be able to describe most valid input and output expessions. The metadata for the property in question is this:

```
<Property Name="CntyCD" Type="Edm.String" frads:DisplayName="County"/>
```

Unfortunately, as this property is described as a `String` with no validation or other constraints, and there are no further annotations regarding this property in the $metadata, then there is no further information that can be found using the standards simply because their schema is not well designed to allow you to obtain any further information.

> So this isn't a deficiency in the OData Protocol itself, just a deficiency in the specific API that you are querying.

A common way to specify that one property is dependant on a specific list of values is to include a navigation property, or at least to specify that a property returns a collection or instance of a complex type. if we look at the [TripPinService](https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/$metadata) you can see this type of information:

```
<EntityType Name="Person">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="UserName"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="26"/>
  <Property Name="MiddleName" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="Gender" Type="Trippin.PersonGender" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Age" Type="Edm.Int64"/>
  <Property Name="Emails" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
  <Property Name="AddressInfo" Type="Collection(Trippin.Location)"/>
  <Property Name="HomeAddress" Type="Trippin.Location"/>
  <Property Name="FavoriteFeature" Type="Trippin.Feature" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Features" Type="Collection(Trippin.Feature)" Nullable="false"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="Friends" Type="Collection(Trippin.Person)"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="BestFriend" Type="Trippin.Person"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="Trips" Type="Collection(Trippin.Trip)"/>
</EntityType>
```

However even then, the specific validation rules become more data related, even if the structure is correct. We can only inspect data values by querying them from somewhere. In the case of TripPin, it does provide endpoints to lookup the necessary information.

> If there was a finite list of possible static values, then this should be defined in the `$metadata` as an Enum, an example again from TripTip where there is a `PersonGender` enum defined:
>
> ```
> <EnumType Name="PersonGender">
>   <Member Name="Male" Value="0"/>
>   <Member Name="Female" Value="1"/>
>   <Member Name="Unknown" Value="2"/>
> </EnumType>
> ```

As this is a question about *data* and not the *schema*. And this API does not provide an endpoint to return the possible `CntyCD` values then one option is to  query the unique values for `CntyCD` from this table:

```
https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/MasterWebService/PublicApi/frads/v1/odata/gcis/Crossings?$apply=groupby((CntyCD))
```

***NOTE:** This resultset can not be guaranteed to be a finite list of **ALL** possible values, but it might be adequate for your needs.*

When dealing with public or government APIs, when the data structure *assumes* that you must already *know* about some aspects of the data, then they are likely to have published that list of data in a separate location.

A good place to start is to goto the host or root of the API's URL to see if there is any documentation served as html or some other browsable form. In this case https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov does provide a listing and in the menu you can see they have <kbd>Downloads</kbd> and in that list is <kbd>[FRA Auxiliary Tables](https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/OfficeofSafety/publicsite/downloads/Auxilary.aspx)</kbd>

If that information was not available, then the local postal service for any region is usually a great place to start looking for location demographic information.

Comment: Good information. The groupby((CntyCD)) in https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/MasterWebService/PublicApi/frads/v1/odata/gcis/Crossings?$apply=groupby((CntyCD)) query did not appear to do anything other than deliver the same payload that https://safetydata.fra.dot.gov/MasterWebService/PublicApi/frads/v1/odata/gcis/Crossings? delivered, however. Note that a valid token needs to be provided to access the data, which I did do, but groupby apparently has to effect.

Comment: *has no effect - sorry couldn’t edit my comment to fix my typo.

Comment: That means that this is not a fully OData v4 compliant service. That's just disappointing must be a simple WCF port. Your solution here will be entirely custom unfortunately.